# Change class name based on text mentioned in the box in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

i am trying to change the current class name prefix.

Here is how my html looks like:

```
<div class="add_multi_category_block">
   <div class="form-group">
      <div class="col-md-2">
         <a id="add_category" class="control-label  add_category">Add multiple category</a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-10">
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="form-group main_category">
      <div class="col-md-1 rowCountNumber" style="text-align: right;">0</div>
      <div class="col-md-2"><input type="text" class="form-control col-md-3" name="main_category[]" id="" value="" placeholder=""></div>
      <div class="col-md-1"><a class="add_sub_category main_category0 btn btn-circle green-sharp btn-sm" title="Add Sub Category"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></a></div>
      <div class="col-md-1"><a class="remove_category btn btn-circle red-haze btn-sm nav-item tooltips"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></a></div>
   </div>
   <div class="form-group main_category">
      <div class="col-md-1 rowCountNumber" style="text-align: right;">1</div>
      <div class="col-md-2"><input type="text" class="form-control col-md-3" name="main_category[]" id="" value="" placeholder=""></div>
      <div class="col-md-1"><a class="add_sub_category main_category1 btn btn-circle green-sharp btn-sm" title="Add Sub Category"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></a></div>
      <div class="col-md-1"><a class="remove_category btn btn-circle red-haze btn-sm nav-item tooltips"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></a></div>
   </div>
   <div class="form-group sub_category_1">
      <div class="col-md-2 rowCountNumber" style="text-align: right;">1.0</div>
      <div class="col-md-2"><input type="text" class="form-control col-md-3" name="sub_category_[]" id="" value="" placeholder=""></div>
      <div class="col-md-1"><a class="btn green-sharp btn-circle btn-sm add_sub_category add_sub_category_1" data-placement="top" data-original-title="Add Sub Category" title="Add Sub Category"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></a></div>
      <div class="col-md-1"><a class="remove_category btn btn-circle red-haze btn-sm "><i class="fa fa-times"></i></a></div>
   </div>
   <div class="form-group sub_category_1">
      <div class="col-md-2 rowCountNumber" style="text-align: right;">1.1</div>
      <div class="col-md-2"><input type="text" class="form-control col-md-3" name="sub_category_[]" id="" value="" placeholder=""></div>
      <div class="col-md-1"><a class="btn green-sharp btn-circle btn-sm add_sub_category add_sub_category_1" data-placement="top" data-original-title="Add Sub Category" title="Add Sub Category"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></a></div>
      <div class="col-md-1"><a class="remove_category btn btn-circle red-haze btn-sm "><i class="fa fa-times"></i></a></div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Here is how it looks like when its get arranged in HTML with CSS, check below screenshot:

[image]

**Now the problem is, i can have N level of childs here. Here i just want to do is, if i remove "0" column, then it should update the below column from "1" to "0" and sub-sequent child's should be**

```
0
 0.0
  0.0.0
  0.0.1
 0.1
```

and so on...with the below number as well. So for the time being i used this below code to remove all the child under one parent.

Here is how it looks like.

```
$(document).on('click', '.remove_category', function(){
    var parentRowCount = $(this).closest('.form-group').find('.rowCountNumber').html();
    var subCategory = parentRowCount.replace(/[ .]/g, "_");

    $(this).closest('.form-group').remove();
    $("*[class*='sub_category_"+subCategory+"']").remove();


    var i = 0;
    $('.main_category').each(function(){
        $(this).find('.rowCountNumber').html(i);  /*----------This will change the number of outer columns but not of the childs -------*/ 
        i++;
    });
});
```

Is there any way to rename all the child with all sub level child at the same time?

For your understanding i am adding one more screenshot of show you how complexity increases here.

[image]

Thank you!

Comment: Please jsfiddle.net/hL6jqryz this jsfiddle link. This dont have very good view of how it looks. but you will get idea about the functionality.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to do another loop of all the sub-level elements and change the numbers. Below is the relevant code change.

```
$('.main_category').each(function(i,v){  // added "i" for index value
   var previousNumber = $(this).find('.rowCountNumber').html(); // gets you the old number
   var subClassName = 'sub_category_'+ previousNumber;  // get the possible sub element class names

   $(this).find('.rowCountNumber').html(i);

   $('.add_multi_category_block [class="'+ subClassName +'"]').each(function(subIndex,elem){
      $(elem).removeClass(subClassName).addClass('sub_category_' + i);
      $(elem).find('.rowCountNumber').html( i + '.' + subIndex );
   });

  //i++; not required as the default callback provides you the index value.
});
```

Note: I have also changed certain code for better performance, Other changes which you can consider is

instead of `$("*[class*='sub_category_"+subCategory+"']").remove();` use

`$(".add_multi_category_block [class='sub_category_"+subCategory+"']").remove();`  This will limit jquery to search only within the specified parent div `.add_multi_category_block`.

Comment: No there is no error. But the logic is incorrect. As i can have multiple levels of child's so its removing rows correctly, but the below same level is not updating.

Comment: @user3201500 oh!! I am sorry... is it possible for you to create a jsFiddle? so that I can test my code there and get the right solution?

Comment: Sure i am just trying to do the same. So we can figure out better solution.

Comment: @user3201500 omg you have many levels deep... :o I need to change the logic then.. I am just looking one level deep.. Also this might also mean we need to take a different approach than only depending on the class names and the number in the html..

Comment: Please https://jsfiddle.net/hL6jqryz/ this jsfiddle link. This dont have very good view of how it looks. but you will get idea about the functionality.

Comment: @user3201500 how much time do you have? Like can I give the logic in next 14 hours?

Comment: Sure no problem. I am also trying to figure out a solution for this.

Comment: @user3201500 cant we change the layout of the div's? like instead of having every div on its own cant we nest the child divs inside parent div?? this way we have more control over them.. right now we need to play with the `class` which will require more logic and complex.. just checking if its possible.. if yes then i can work on that idea.

Comment: Actually my current system is build on top of that only. I have figured something on a basic level with classes for now. But you can try with nested  divs as well, if that makes easy. I will generate new CSS.